# As soon as user click on edit pencil Icon, It should open a new modal dialog

Tags: angular, html, css, bootstrap-4

As soon as user click on edit pencil Icon, It should open a new modal dialog for user to upload a new photo,
But presently If I Click on the edit pencil Icon, a local system folder will open to upload a new pic..  [For Example : In stackoverflow >>In Body , If I want to upload an Image I will click on Image Icon so it will open a new modal box to upload a photo ....Same I need like that scenario ..Please help me in this Thanks in Advance... [image]

```js
onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0])
      var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.imagePath = event.target['result'];
      this.isPhotoEditted = true;
      this.onSave();
    }
  }
```

```html
<input #inputFile type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" style="visibility: hidden;" />

<div class="outer-div-for-the-imgae-icon">
                            <app-image [imagesrc]="imagePath" style="width : 38%; margin-top: 30px;"
                                class="d-none d-sm-block" alt="..."></app-image>
                            <i (click)="inputFile.click()" style="color : white;left:37%; 
                            position: absolute; top: 24px; padding: 3px; background-color:#0076C8; 
                            border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                                class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
```

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Please create a stackBlitz if possible!

Comment: Hi @Prashant  No error but currently local desktop floder  will  to open , Instead of that I need modal dilaog box

Comment: For ex? Like this:https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Yes yes exactly Like that only, But onclick on that Icon It should open the Modal dialog  ... Please help me in this ....

Comment: As I know you can't do that because JavaScript has its own file browse dialog!